# Trained neural network produces different predictions with same data (TensorFlow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I have trained a neural network with TensorFlow. After training i saved it and loaded it again in a new '. py' file to avoid retraining on accident. As i was testing it with some extra data i found out that it predicts different things for the same data. Should it not theoretically compute the same thing for the same data?

Some information
feed forward net
4 hidden layers with 900 neurons each
5000 training epochs
reached accuracy of ~80%
data was normalized using normalize from sklearn. preprocessing
cost function: tensorflow.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
optimizer: tf.train.AdamOptimizer
I am giving my network the data as a matrix, same way i used for training. (each row containing a data sample, having as many columns as there are input neurons)

Out of ten prediction cycles with the same data my network produces different results in at least 2 cycles (max observed 4 so far)
How can this be. By theory all that is happening are data processing calculations of the form W_i*x_i + b_i. As my x_i, W_i and b_i do not change anymore how come that the prediction varies? May there be a mistake in model reloading routine?

```
with tf.Session() as sess:  
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('path to .meta')  
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('path to checkpoints'))  
    result = (sess.run(tf.argmax(prediction.eval(feed_dict=x:input_data}),1)))  
    print(result)
```

Comment: Possibly uses some weights somewhere which you didn't define but are randomly initialized?

Comment: Check two things. Is the behavior same with .pb file? How do you generate input_data?

Comment: I use tf train Saver. which saves my net as xy ckpt. The standard routine saves several files: xy ckpt data, xy ckpt meta, xy ckpt index and checkpoints. I will try to use .pb and tell about my observations. I use matplotlib pyplot to read in my images, normalize them with normalize from sklearn, ravel it to 1d array and pack the in a list which is than converted to numpy array with dtype float32.

Comment: I have tested with .pb file format. -> No change
I have tried feeding my data row by row -> no change
What is mostly strange is that it either classifies all given data correct or all given data wrong, there is no variation within prediction (like 80 correct out of 100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a really stupid mistake by me. Now it works fine with loading the model from a save. The problem was caused by the global variables initializer. If you leave it out, it will work fine. The previously found information may prove useful for someone so i will leave it here. Solution is now:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver.restore(sess, 'path to your saved file C:x/y/z/model/model.ckpt')
```

After this you can go on as usually. I do not really know why variables initializer prevents this from working. As i see it, it should be something like: initialize all variables to exist and with random values and then got to that saved file and use values from there, but apparently something else happens...

Answer (score -1):

So i have been doing some testing and found out the following about this problem.
As i have been trying to reuse my created model i had to use the tf.global_variables_initializer(). By doing so it has overwritten my imported graph and all the values were random, which explains different network outputs. This still left me with a problem to solve: how do i load my network? The workaround i am currently using is not optimal by far but it at least allows me to use my saved model. Tensor flow allows one to give unique names to the functions and tensors used. By doing so i could access them through the graph:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('path to .meta')  
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('path to checkpoints'))
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    graph.get_tensor_by_name('name:0')
```

Using this method i could access all my saved values, but they were separated! It means that i had 1x weight and 1x bias per operation used, which led to a bunch of new variables. If you do not know the names, use following:

```
print(graph.get_all_collection_keys())
```

This prints the collection names (our variables are stored in collections)

```
print(graph.get_collection('name'))
```

This allows us to access the collection as see what are the names/keys for our variables.

This led to another problem. I could no longer use my model as global variables initializer had everything overwritten. By thus i had to redefine the whole model manually with weight and biases that i got previously.

Unfortunately, this is the only thing i could come up with. If anyone has a better idea, please let me know.

The whole thing with mistake looked like this:

```
imports...
placeholders for data...

def my_network(data):
    ## network definition with tf functions ##
return output

def train_my_net():
    prediction = my_network(data)
    cost function
    optimizer
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        for i in how many epochs i want:
            training routine
            save

def use_my_net():
    prediction = my_network(data)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('path to .meta')  
        saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('path to checkpoints'))
        print(sess.run(prediction.eval(feed_dict={placeholder:data})))
graph = tf.get_default_graph()
```